# Wire Tank Topper/High Rise for Leopard Gecko?

Tags: leopard-geckos, enclosure

My leopard gecko currently has a ten gallon tank. She is doing perfectly well, but I want her to have more space so she can be as happy as possible. I'm looking into creating a second floor for her enclosure. I would like a Tank Topper / High Rise addition such as this one [https://www.amazon.com/You-Me-Small-Animal-Topper/dp/B01MYOQ1QR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MYOQ1QR).

Is a wire topper okay for my gecko? I have solutions for any potential problems I can think of, which I will list here:

Heat: I use an UTH for my Leopard Gecko, and her lighting can provides any additional heat needed as well. The UTH would remain where it is and the lights would be positioned on either side of the slanted rooftop shape of this tank (I can use the lamp clips and add support to keep them in place with zip ties if needed.)

Humidity: While I use Eco Earth on the ground floor of her tank at the moment, the second floor can be covered with some reptile carpet I have. I can cut it to fit the floor, and this will help keep the humidity in the bottom. Also, the Eco Earth holds moisture and humidity well. If needed, I could add a humid hide to the second floor of the cage.

Feeders escaping: I rarely feed my Leopard Gecko crickets anymore, and none of her feeders would be able to escape via the second floor since she eats mainly mealworms from a dish. On the occasion that I do feed her crickets, I tend to feed her in a separate area, not in her tank, because the crickets like to hide inside her tree and are nearly impossible to find.

Falling: The tank topper I am looking at getting has a full floor, with only one opening for the ramp, so I cannot think of anyway she would fall from the second floor. There is no reason why she would fall off the ramp, but if an accident happened she would only fall a couple inches onto her Eco Earth substrate. She would not be hurt. She is also a very strong climber and enjoys climbing on her tree inside her tank and on pretty much everything else when I have her out of her tank.

Please let me know what if you see any problems with this idea. I want to make sure I am making a good decision and providing a safe and happy enclosure for her with plenty of space.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so 1) I totally agree with your idea of giving your leopard gecko more space, and I'll give you some of my input/opinion on the example you gave as a topper, but 2) you're not quite in question form, so I'm going to answer as if you asked "is this topper safe for adding space for my leopard gecko".

So the topper example you gave a link to is a cool concept BUT it's not actually adding that much surface space. I saw you mentioned yours isn't the exact picture, but take the following opinion based on what I'm able to see, and about wire toppers in general. Check out the actual level at the top of the ramps(of the one pictured, but also take into consideration if it also pertains to the one you're interested in) it's small, and isn't adding that much to your current 10gal. And there are pros and cons to wire toppers; the pros are that it allows good air flow for the cage, but this doesn't outweigh the con, in my opinion. The con with wire toppers is that reptiles can get their toes and toe nails/claws stuck in the wire grating and can end up hurting them, by either accidentally amputation (which can cause infection), or the nail could get stuck and ripped off (also could get infected). Any open injuries caused by grating can then get packed with feces, bedding or food bits, adding to the existing pain of losing a claw, toe or foot.

If at all possible I would upgrade to a "long" version of a larger tank... Like a 20gal long or a 30gal long. This topper is already $30ish and you could get a new or used larger tank for around the same price(if not less if used), and you will end up with WAY more surface area than a topper (plus less chance of injury).

If you choose to upgrade, you will still want a locking lid for safety. Going with a used tank upgrade, be sure to check for cracks before purchasing (find one without cracks or chips on the inside that could also injure) and make sure to clean it and rinse very well before setting it up. I'd recommend using a cleaner specifically safe for reptile enclosures. The more surface space you provide for him, sill not only gives him more space to roam for exercise and a sound mind but will give you more space to add hiding huts or decor for him to feel safe. It's also important for geckos to have one side of their tank to be dedicated for cool down, for when they no longer want/need to be under their heat lamp. This is something that is difficult to provide with a 10gal.

Hope this helps.. If it was not the answer to your needs, please change your post into more of a question format, detailing your specific question.

I've added two pics/screenshots, 1) reflecting an example of a 20 gallon long aquarium in the same price range as your topper and 2) an example of a reptile cage cleaner, safe for your gecko.
[image: 20gal long]

[image: example of reptile cage cleaner]